# Llenar DataGridview en C#, consulta Linq y Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, linq, entity-framework-6

Consulta Base de Datos[image: Consulta SQL]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dese obtener el mismo resultado mediante Linq, lo hago de esta manera pero no me regresa nada.

```
  public void cargarValoresVariables(DataGridView control, List<string> Variables)
    {
        var lista = from p in be.CatVariable
                    join s in be.BalValorVariable on p.CatVariableId equals s.CatVariableId
                    join c in be.CatFilosofia on p.CatFilosofiaId equals c.CatFilosofiaId
                    where (c.Nombre == (this.NombreFase))
                    where c.Parent_CatFilosofiaId == (this.Parent_CatFilosofiaId)
                    where s.FechaReal == (this.fechaReal)
                    select new { p.Nombre, s.ValorNumerico, s.ValorCadena };
        control.DataSource = lista.ToList();              

    }
```

Comment: intentaste quitando la parte del `where` a ver si retorna registros y despues agregandolos de a uno para ver cual causa que no retorne datos

Comment: porque defines varios `where` en lugar de usar el `&&` o `||` para represetnar el AND o el OR

Comment: en el `sql` no veo que en el ON estas relaciondo el campo `CatFilosofiaId` estas aplicando los filtros que deberian ir en el WHERE, revisa la query sql porque es incorrecta

Comment: @LeandroTuttini en el caso del CatFilosofía de SQL deje un Left Join. Y agregando el ON me regresa los mismos Datos. he probado los Where pero Aún sí.

Comment: vuelvo a remarcar que el sql es incorrecto, no igualas nunca el `cf.CatFilosofiaId = cv.CatFilosofiaId` como si intentas hacerlo en linq. Por lo tanto la respuesta que tengas en el sql puede ser diferente a la que obtienes en el linq. Ademas tu mismo te respondes en el sql dejaste un left join, pero en el linq no, pr eso los datos que obtienes no son los mismos